# Need assistance with HTML

Tags: html

I am very new to HTML and I am trying to edit my website.

What I am doing is adding more games shown here:
https://cosmicgameservers.com/game-servers.html

On the second line, it shifts all the way to the forth spot and then the next added one follows the correct path. Any ideas?

I plan to have 16 boxes so if anyone finds the fix and posts the correct HTML code, please leave 16 place holders.

Thanks.

CODE:

```html
<head>
  <title>Cosmic Game Servers | Premium Game Server Hosting | Game Servers</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Cosmic Game Servers offers premium dedicated starbound, minecraft, and 7 days to die game (7dtd) servers for the cheapest prices with no lag, along with award winning support.">
  <meta name=keywords content="minecraft,starbound,premium,game,voice,web,dedicated,server,hosting,support" ">
<meta name=author content="Blake Simpson ">
<link rel="shortcut icon " href=favicon.ico>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="js/html5shiv.js "></script>
 <![endif]-->
<link rel=stylesheet href="css/main.css " type="text/css " id=main-css>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js "></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js "></script>
<script src="js/easing.js "></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js "></script>
<script src="js/selectnav.js "></script>
<script src="js/ender.js "></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lazyload.js "></script>
<script src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js "></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js "></script>
<script src="js/custom.js "></script>
<script src="js/rev-setting-1.js "></script>
</head>
<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create','UA-43467308-2','auto');ga('send','pageview');</script>
<body>
<div id=wrapper>
<header>
<div class=container>
<div id=logo>
<div class=inner>
<a href=index.html>
<img src="images/cosmiclogotrans.png " alt=logo></a>
</div>
</div>
<ul id=mainmenu>
<li><a href=index.html>Home</a></li>
<li><a href=game-servers.html>Game Servers</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=minecraft-servers.html>Minecraft</a></li>
<li><a href=starbound-servers.html>Starbound</a></li>
<li><a href=game-servers.html>Other Game Servers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href=voice-servers.html>Voice Servers</a>
</li>
<li><a href=web-hosting.html>Web Hosting</a>
</li>
<li><a>VPS/Dedicated</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=vps-servers.html>VPS Servers</a></li>
<li><a href=dedicated-servers.html>Dedicated Servers</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href=about.html>About</a></li>
<li><a href=contact.html>Contact</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=sponsorships.html>Sponsorships</a></li>
<li><a href=affiliates.html>Affiliates</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>Customer Login</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="/billing/login.php ">Billing Panel</a></li>
<li><a href="http://panel.cosmicgameservers.com ">Minecraft Server Panel</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
                <!-- mainmenu close -->

            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- header close -->

        <!-- subheader begin -->
        <div id="subheader ">
            <div class="container ">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="span12 ">
                        <h1>Game Servers</h1>
                        <span>Your favorite game servers all in one place.</span>
                        <ul class="crumb ">
                            <li><a href="index.html ">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="sep ">/</li>
                            <li>Game Servers</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- subheader close -->

        <!-- content begin -->
        <div id="content ">
            <div class="container ">
            
            <div class="span11 alert alert-success ">
            <font size="5 ">We currently have <strong>25% OFF</strong> ALL of our products with the promotional code <strong>25OFF</strong></font>
           </div>
            
                <div class="row ">
                    <!-- team member -->
                    <div class="team span3 ">
                    
                        <div class="picframe ">
                        <a href="minecraft-servers.html ">
                            <span class="overlay ">
                            
                                <span class="sb-icons ">
                                    <img src="images/arrow.png " height="32 " width="32 " alt=" ">
                                </span>
                                <span class="pf_text ">
                                 <span class="project-name ">Minecraft Servers</span>
                                </span>
                               
                            </span>
                            </a>
                       <img src="images/games/minecraft.jpg " data-original="images/games/minecraft.jpg " class="team-pic " alt=" " />
                        </div>
                     
                    </div>
                    <!-- team close -->

                    <!-- team member -->
                    <div class="team span3 ">
                    
                        <div class="picframe ">
                        <a href="starbound-servers.html ">
                            <span class="overlay ">
                            
                                <span class="sb-icons ">
                                    <img src="images/arrow.png " height="32 " width="32 " alt=" ">
                                </span>
                                <span class="pf_text ">
                                 <span class="project-name ">Starbound Servers</span>
                                </span>
                               
                            </span>
                            </a>
                       <img src="images/games/starboundlogo.png " data-original="images/games/starboundlogo.png " class="team-pic " alt=" " />
                        </div>
                     
                    </div>
                    <!-- team close -->

                    <!-- team member -->
                    <div class="team span3 ">
                    
                        <div class="picframe ">
                        <a href="7dtd-servers.html ">
                            <span class="overlay ">
                            
                                <span class="sb-icons ">
                                    <img src="images/arrow.png " height="32 " width="32 " alt=" ">
                                </span>
                                <span class="pf_text ">
                                 <span class="Space-Engineers ">Coming Soon!</span>
                                </span>
                               
                            </span>
                            </a>
                       <img src="images/games/spaceengineers.png " data-original="images/games/spaceengineers.png " class="team-pic " alt=" " />
                        </div>
                     
                    </div>
                    <!-- team close -->
                    
                    <!-- team member -->
                    <div class="team span3 ">
                    
                        <div class="picframe ">
                        <a href=" ">
                            <span class="overlay ">
                            
                                <span class="sb-icons ">
                                    <img src="images/arrow.png " height="32 " width="32 " alt=" ">
                                </span>
                                <span class="pf_text ">
                                 <span class="Rust ">Coming Soon!</span>
                                </span>
                               
                            </span>
                            </a>
                       <img src="images/games/rust.jpg " data-original="images/games/rust.jpg " class="team-pic " alt="Rust " />
                        </div>
                     
                    </div>
                    <!-- team close -->

                    <!-- team member -->
                    <div class="team span3 ">
                    
                        <div class="picframe ">
                        <a href="minecraft-servers.html ">
                            <span class="overlay ">
                            
                                <span class="sb-icons ">
                                    <img src="images/arrow.png " height="32 " width="32 " alt=" ">
                                </span>
                                <span class="pf_text ">
                                 <span class="project-name ">Minecraft Servers</span>
                                </span>
                               
                            </span>
                            </a>
                       <img src="images/games/minecraft.jpg " data-original="images/games/minecraft.jpg " class="team-pic " alt=" " />
                        </div>
                     
                    </div>
                    <!-- team close -->

                    <!-- team member -->
                    <div class="team span3 ">
                    
                        <div class="picframe ">
                        <a href="minecraft-servers.html ">
                            <span class="overlay ">
                            
                                <span class="sb-icons ">
                                    <img src="images/arrow.png " height="32 " width="32 " alt=" ">
                                </span>
                                <span class="pf_text ">
                                 <span class="project-name ">Minecraft Servers</span>
                                </span>
                               
                            </span>
                            </a>
                       <img src="images/games/minecraft.jpg " data-original="images/games/minecraft.jpg " class="team-pic " alt=" " />
                        </div>
                     
                    </div>
                    <!-- team close -->

                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- content close -->

        <!-- footer begin -->
        <footer>
            <div class="container ">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="span4 ">
                        <img src="images/cosmiclogotrans.png " alt=" "><br><br>
                        "There is only one boss. The customer. And he can fire everybody in the company from the chairman on down, simply by spending his money somewhere else. " -Sam Walton
                        <br>

That quote is our companies guidance. Our number one priority is our clients. Without clients, a company will be nothing. That is why we try our hardest to give you as much as we can when it comes from the best servers to the most rapid support. 
                    </div>

                                    

                    <div class="span4 ">
                        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                        <div class="widget widget-address ">
                            <address>
                                <a href="http://cosmicgameservers.com/billing/submitticket.php ">Submit Ticket</a>
                                <span><strong>Twitter:</strong><a href="http://www.twitter.com/CosmicGameServe ">@CosmicGameServe</a>
                                <span><strong>Email:</strong><a href="mailto:contact@cosmicgameservers.com ">contact@cosmicgameservers.com</a></span>
                                <span><strong>Phone:</strong>Coming Soon</span>
                            </address>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 ">
                        <a class="twitter-timeline " href="https://twitter.com/CosmicGameServe " data-widget-id="421589403329253376 ">Tweets by @CosmicGameServe</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js
  ";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script ","twitter-wjs ");</script>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="subfooter ">
                <div class="container ">
                    <div class="row ">
                        <div class="span6 ">
                            &copy; Copyright Cosmic Game Servers 2016 &nbsp;| 
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6 ">
                            <nav>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html ">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="game-servers.html ">Game Servers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="voice-servers.html ">Voice Servers</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html ">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.html ">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </footer>
        <!-- footer close -->

    </div>

    <!-- style switcher
    ================================================== -->
    <script src="js/switcher.js "></script>
    


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should have your `script` tags inside the `head' element or the `body` element.

Comment: I see you are using bootstrap. Using class "span3" will display only 4 elements in a row. Use "span2" for 6 elements in a row.
Check bootstrap documentation. Note your site has bootstrap v2.x and current one is v3.x

Also, max you can have is 12 boxes in a row with class "span1". As bootstrap row is divided into 12 columns

Comment: So you suggest changing the span3's to span1's?